How to run Alembic migrations in multiple PostgreSQL database?
I'm currently experiencing issues running Alembic migrations across multiple PostgreSQL databases. The provided code executes migrations for only the first model, but it fails to process the additional models required.

sqla.py:
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

UnidadeBase = declarative_base()
ImplantacaoBase = declarative_base()
ChamadosBase = declarative_base()


alembic env.py:
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

from databasemgmt.sqla_base import UnidadeBase, ImplantacaoBase, ChamadosBase

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

segments = {
    "Unidade": {
        "metadata": UnidadeBase.metadata,
        "db_url": os.getenv("DB_UNIDADE_URL"),
    },
    "Implantacao": {
        "metadata": ImplantacaoBase.metadata,
        "db_url": os.getenv("DB_IMPLANTACAO_URL"),
    },
    "Chamados": {
        "metadata": ChamadosBase.metadata,
        "db_url": os.getenv("DB_CHAMADOS_URL"),
    }
}

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """

    for segment_name, segment in segments.items():

        url = segment["db_url"]
        metadata = segment["metadata"]

        context.configure(
            url=url,
            target_metadata=metadata,
            literal_binds=True,
            dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    for segment_name, segment in segments.items():

        url = segment["db_url"]
        metadata = segment["metadata"]

        connectable = engine_from_config(
            {"sqlalchemy.url": url},
            prefix="sqlalchemy.",
            poolclass=pool.NullPool,
        )

        with connectable.connect() as connection:
            context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=metadata)

            with context.begin_transaction():
                context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()


Neither the "Implantacao" nor the "Chamados" tables were created after running the command alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Adding table implantacao and chamados".
Is there an alternative approach to handling migrations for multiple databases, or does Alembic not support this functionality?
